# Simple way to compare two objects with unknown stuctures

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have object which describes expected result:

```
{
"property1" : "value1",
"property2" : "value2",
    "property3" :{
        "property4" : "value4"
    }
}
```

I don't care about all the extra properties. For example,in this case, I get actual result like this, and it will be a match, as all expected properties are present and have expected values:

```
{
   "property1":"value1",
   "property2":"value2",
   "property3":{
      "property4":"value4",
      "property5":"value5"
   },
   "property6":"value6"
}
```

And this will not be a match:

```
{
   "property2":"value20",
   "property3":{
      "property4":"value4"
   }
}
```

Difficult part here is that I don't know structure in advance; I need a function that would match any objects.

My best idea so far is to use [lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) to flatten both objects so they look like this:

```
{
       "property1":"value1",
       "property2":"value2",
       "property3.property4":"value4",
       "property3.property5":"value5",
       "property6":"value6"
}
```

After which I can just cycle on all expected properties. This solution feels awkward, though; is there a simpler, easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way using **Lodash's** by `transform` function to iterate over each key-value pair in the input object, and checks if the value is an object using `isObject`. If the value is an object, the implementation creates a nested object using transform again, with a function that concatenates the key with the nested key using dot notation. The nested object is then merged with the result object using assign:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const flattenedObj = _.transform(myObj, function (result, value, key) {
  if (_.isObject(value)) {
    const nestedObj = _.transform(value, function (nestedResult, nestedValue, nestedKey) {
      nestedResult[key + '.' + nestedKey] = nestedValue;
    });
    _.assign(result, nestedObj);
  } else {
    result[key] = value;
  }
});
```

Comment: That's kinda what I originally intended to do; thanks for suggesting transform

Answer (score 0):

Iterate recursively over the object's properties and checking if any of the properties are themselves objects. If an object is found, the function will call itself with the nested object as input and then iterate over its properties.

```js
function flattenObject(obj, parentKey = "") {
  let flattened = {};

  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      let newKey = parentKey ? parentKey + "." + key : key;

      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        let nestedObj = flattenObject(obj[key], newKey);
        flattened = { ...flattened,
          ...nestedObj
        };
      } else {
        flattened[newKey] = obj[key];
      }
    }
  }

  return flattened;
}
const myObj = {
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2",
  "property3": {
    "property4": "value4",
    "property5": "value5"
  },
  "property6": "value6"
};

const flattenedObj = flattenObject(myObj);
console.log(flattenedObj);
```